# Сгенерировать числа с указанным средним арифметическим

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Мне нужно сгенерировать `argv[2]` чисел, среднее арифметическое которых - `argv[1]`. Также все числа должны быть от `argv[1] - argv[3]` до `argv[1] + argv[3]`. На выходе должны быть числа с тремя цифрами после запятой. Последняя цифра должна быть либо **0**, либо **5** (Четвёртый аргумент, как в коде ниже необязательный).

У меня есть такой код:

```py
from sys import argv, exit
from random import uniform, random, randint, normalvariate

try:
    chislo = float(argv[1])
    count = int(argv[2])
    predel = float(argv[3])
except IndexError:
    print("Требуется минимум 4 аргумента")
    exit()
except ValueError:
    print("Аргументы должны быть числом")
    exit()
minm = 0

def flost(n):
    return float(f"{float(n):.3f}")

fn = flost(uniform(chislo - predel, chislo + predel))

numbers = [fn]

def rnd(num):
    num = str(num)
    a = num[len(num) - 1]
    if int(a) > 4:
        return num[:len(num) - 1] + "0"
    else:
        return num[:len(num) - 1] + "5"

for i in range(count - 2):
    fn = chislo * 2 - fn
    fn = normalvariate(chislo, predel)
    fn = flost(rnd(flost(fn)))
    numbers.append(fn)

numbers.append(flost(chislo * 2 - fn + minm))

newn = []
for i in numbers:
    l = str(i)
    while len(l.split(".")[1]) < 3:
        l += "0"
    newn.append(l)

newn = sorted(newn, key = lambda A: random())

arr = []
for i in newn:
    arr.append(float(i))
print(arr)

for i, e in enumerate(newn):
    print(f"{str(i + 1)}. {e}")

print("Среднее арифметическое:")
print(sum(arr) / len(arr))
```

Я запускаю его при помощи `python main.py 10.185 72 0.05 0.005` и получаю

```py
[10.22, 10.195, 10.12, 10.17, 10.245, 10.228, 10.185, 10.14, 10.195, 10.1, 10.1, 10.195, 10.145, 10.15, 10.285, 10.19, 10.285, 10.205, 10.155, 10.15, 10.15, 10.17, 10.185, 10.185, 10.07, 10.2, 10.16, 10.105, 10.155, 10.2, 10.22, 10.195, 10.225, 10.1, 10.25, 10.125, 10.24, 10.3, 10.15, 10.265, 10.155, 10.18, 10.22, 10.15, 10.205, 10.195, 10.1, 10.255, 10.085, 10.17, 10.185, 10.23, 10.19, 10.195, 10.11, 10.21, 10.255, 10.21, 10.175, 10.205, 10.16, 10.27, 10.155, 10.185, 10.23, 10.155, 10.12, 10.17, 10.16, 10.085, 10.2, 10.22]
1. 10.220
2. 10.195
3. 10.120
4. 10.170
5. 10.245
6. 10.228
7. 10.185
8. 10.140
9. 10.195
10. 10.100
11. 10.100
12. 10.195
13. 10.145
14. 10.150
15. 10.285
16. 10.190
17. 10.285
18. 10.205
19. 10.155
20. 10.150
21. 10.150
22. 10.170
23. 10.185
24. 10.185
25. 10.070
26. 10.200
27. 10.160
28. 10.105
29. 10.155
30. 10.200
31. 10.220
32. 10.195
33. 10.225
34. 10.100
35. 10.250
36. 10.125
37. 10.240
38. 10.300
39. 10.150
40. 10.265
41. 10.155
42. 10.180
43. 10.220
44. 10.150
45. 10.205
46. 10.195
47. 10.100
48. 10.255
49. 10.085
50. 10.170
51. 10.185
52. 10.230
53. 10.190
54. 10.195
55. 10.110
56. 10.210
57. 10.255
58. 10.210
59. 10.175
60. 10.205
61. 10.160
62. 10.270
63. 10.155
64. 10.185
65. 10.230
66. 10.155
67. 10.120
68. 10.170
69. 10.160
70. 10.085
71. 10.200
72. 10.220
Среднее арифметическое:
10.181916666666668
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На маленькой выборке получить число близкое к матожиданию в рамках стандартных библиотек получения псевдослучайной величины очень сложно. Плюс Вы еще дополнительно корректируете величину значений в выборке кратно 0.005.

Отсюда можно пойти рядом путей:

1. Для малых выборок в цикле крутить новую выборку до нужной дельты.
2. Высчитывать на последних шагах необходимые значения (доводя искусственно выборку до нужного матожидания)
3. Либо увеличивать выборку.

Я немного другой код сделал, но работать примерно должно аналогично. Посмотрите результаты у себя или в моем коде для выборок 72, 1000, 10000.

```
import random

mean = 10.185
count = 1000
limits = 0.05
toler = 0.005
args = [mean, count, limits, toler]

nums = [round(random.uniform(args[0] - args[2], args[0] + args[2])*int(1/args[3]))/int(1/args[3]) for i in range(args[1])]
print(min(nums))
print(max(nums))
print(sum(nums)/len(nums))
```

Вариант с прогоном выборки в цикле. Да он затратный, но можно получить выборку со средним с заданной погрешностью. При этом с ростом выборки мы будет стремиться к нужному матожиданию, что снизит число итераций на пересборку выборки.

```
import random

mean = 10.185
count = 72
limits = 0.05
toler = 0.005
delta = 0.0002
args = [mean, count, limits, toler, delta]

d = args[0]
while d >= args[4]:
    nums = [round(random.uniform(args[0] - args[2], args[0] + args[2])*int(1/args[3]))/int(1/args[3]) for i in range(args[1])]
    d = abs(args[0] - sum(nums)/len(nums))

print(min(nums))
print(max(nums))
print(sum(nums)/len(nums))
print(nums)
```

Comment: Поправил ссылки на массив с переменными.

Answer (score 1):

В функции `rnd(n)` создаётся погрешность в сторону уменьшения (в среднем). В результате сумма случайных чисел всегда будет меньше, чем заданное число.

Comment: Я уже пытался запускать код без `rnd()`, но погрешность всё равно была (примерно `0.0002`). Как вообще сделать так, чтобы функция `rnd(n)` возвращала результат, с погрешностью минимум `0.0002`?

Comment: 0.0002 наверное уже набирается за счёт двоичной арифметики. Я бы генерировал на одно число меньше, а потом последнее бы просто вычислял, чтобы сумма была подходящая.

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы `rnd(n)` возвращал результат с погрешностью максимум `0.001`?

Comment: Увеличить число случаев или вычислять последнюю величину самому. А почему Вы не используете `random.normalvariate()`? В нем можно матожидание и разброс задать.

Comment: @Werryx для одного конкретного числа никак, потому что последняя цифра должна быть 0 или 5. Поэтому погрешность будет 0, 0.001 или 0.002.

Comment: @AndyPavlov Я переделал через `normalvariate()`, обновлённый код в ответе

Comment: Причем от 0 до 0.002 это в правильной реализации. У вас погрешность может быть до 0.009.

Comment: @Werryx я обновил свой ответ для результата с заданной точностью через пересборку списка в цикле до достижения нужного результата. Вариант, конечно, затратный, но с ростом выборки будет требоваться меньшее количество пересборок из-за стремления выборки к матожиданию.